# Adding PostgreSQL database to web map

Tags: postgis, postgresql, leaflet, spatial-database

I am interested in learning how to add a PostgreSQL database to a web map so I can do functions like select by attributes or locations. I am using Leaflet API to make the web map.

What are the necessary steps to integrate a PostgreSQL database into a Leaflet?

Answer (score 9):

You can't talk directly from a web browser to a database, because a browser runs code on a client's computer, and that doesn't (and shouldn't) connect directly to your database.

What you need is a piece of middleware that converts a request from your code to a Postgresql query, and returns data that Leaflet can understand.

Depending on how complex your data and what you know how to write code in, you could write something basic in a server programming language, like Python or JavaScript and run it in a light framework, like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Feathers](http://feathersjs.com/).

Or you can grab something bigger, like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/), which already has it's API developed (it's called WFS, and is an open standard) and knows how to talk to PostGIS, including doing parameterised queries and views.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [useful script](https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON) by Bryan McBride. It's a PHP script that returns geojson from PostgreSQL-PostGIS database.

Also, check out his [bootleaf template](https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf).

Answer (score 0):

Well I just made up an API server that queries the DB (PostgreSQL or MySQL) and returns GeoJSON on-the-fly. I have tested with the Fetch API and Axios that they can be used to GET the GeoJSON (from an URL like `localhost:5000/postgres/api/<table-name>` and add it as a layer to Leaflet.

You can clone the repo from [Github](https://github.com/sudiptog81/sql2geojson) and set some variables in `server.js` to start the server. The URL changes to `localhost:5000/mysql/api/<table-name>?fields=<field-1>,<field-2>...and so on` if you decide to use MySQL.

You can also filter by attributes by specifying which attributes to filter by and the filter keyword (for instance, `localhost:5000/postgres/api/test?fields=name&filter=ABC` provided that you have an existing table with `test` table name and have attribute `name` in the table and an feature with attribute `name` equal to `ABC`.

Demo is hosted at https://sql2geojson.herokuapp.com/